# Linking Action Pack MSDN $100 credits to existing Azure Account

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, msdn

Has anyone linked an existing Azure portal account with Action Pack to use $100 credits/month that comes with Action Pack?

I've an action pack and also a separate account which I used for my Azure subscription before buying Action Pack.

Comment: i strongly suspect this wouldn't work, but this question is best address to a support representative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. After some investigation and liaising with MS support this is how I achieved it.

1. Link the existing azure email to your Action Pack and assign "view product keys" privileges to it.
2. Go to [msppdd.microsoft.com/msppdd](http://msppdd.microsoft.com/msppdd) and click on "Microsoft Online Services" -> Azure Monthly Credits -> Click the link under Special Instruction on that page -> Click Active Benefits.

   Note: If you are facing issues activating through this route then go to [portal.azure.com](http://portal.azure.com) and create a support ticket asking them to link your Action Pack credits with this account. Do mention the Partner ID in the ticket. (This is possible only through backend)
3. Once done you will be able to see Monthly Partner Network under list of your subscriptions, as shown in image below.

[image]

Comment: I'm struggling to see what the point is of a new "Microsoft Partner Network" subscription when I already have an existing subscription. They are basically giving me $100/month which I can't use